# How can I overlay a div including an iframe with external source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that I want to show a div overlay with a popup. Basically, like colorbox. But I want this to be permanent. They should not be able to click out of the div. Inside of the div should be contents from popsurvey.com in an iframe. The link I need to frame is this -> http://www.popsurvey.com/s/5gzmqc/0x5513 - How do you recommend this be done? Thanks.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"620", height:"591", href:"http://www.popsurvey.com/s/5gzmqc/4zk4lm?embed=true", opacity: ".3"});
});
 </script>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  That's a basic question you must ask if you want help here.  Nobody is going to go out of their way to write code for you, especially for some popup spam.  This site is for learning.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Brad I've tried using colorbox. But I'm not sure how to get it to where a user cannot click out. Ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest not doing it.  Preventing a user from clicking out of such an intrusive popup to begin with does not provide a good user experience.  Is there some reason you need this functionality?  Also, post your code.

Comment: This could be seen as an attempt at [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), FYI. I assume in your case there is no secret linking hiding beneath the content, but be aware that overlaying content from two origins is a huge red flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a solution in jquery which is light enough and simple enough to suit your needs (I hope), Clean and simple is usually the best way to do these sort of things and 99.99% of the time it's pretty redundant to use larger plugins or prebuilt solutions.

- [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eT2Lz/10/embedded/result/)
- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eT2Lz/10/)

---

The html:

```
   <div id="block"></div>
<div id="iframecontainer">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>​
```

The css:

```
#iframecontainer {width:90%; height: 90%; display: none; position: fixed;margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 5%; background:#FFF; border: 1px solid #666;border: 1px solid #555;box-shadow: 2px 2px 40px #222;z-index: 999999;}
#iframecontainer iframe {display:none; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; border: none; }
#loader {background: url('http://www.calgaryramsrugby.com/images/ajax-loader.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;  width: 250px; height: 250px; margin:auto;}
#block {background: #000; opacity:0.6;  position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top:0; left:0; display:none;}​
```

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#block').fadeIn();
    $('#iframecontainer').fadeIn();
    $('#iframecontainer iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.popsurvey.com/s/5gzmqc/0x5513');
    $('#iframecontainer iframe').load(function() {
        $('#loader').fadeOut(function() {
            $('iframe').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

​

​

Comment: did you make sure you added a $(document).ready() function around the jquery? also updating code with a close button and a block to make sure only the close button and the iframe are accessible

Comment: Yes, I have a document.ready() function and its loading. It just screws up the site.

Comment: how so, I can't really fix or change things without knowing what the issue is.

Comment: looks and functionality. Colorbox looked fine but it would let the users click out. I need the div overlay to be permanent.

Comment: wait so you want to permanently disallow the the rest of the site?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the site is inactive.

Comment: Okay, updated again, this time I've made it look nicer and i've made it to what I think you're trying to do. Also, in order to have pretty rounded edges (without using pictures to manually add rounded corners lol) the site inside the iframe needs to have a solid background.

Comment: It's placing the iframe behind everything - http://i.imgur.com/5IoAk.png EDIT: z-index fixed that.